# Docker image reading db properties

Tags: docker, cloud

I have a java program that reads PostgreSQL database using db.properties file which I kept it under C:\opt\xyz\projectname\db.propperties.

Created the Docker image and was able to run on my local Docker container with -v option.

Ex: docker run -itd -v C:/opt/xyz/projectname:/opt/xyz/projectname  projectName:tag

I have moved the image to the Google cloud and want to run the image on Cloud run.

Q: How can setup the db.properties file like I did it on my windows at C:\opt\xyz\projectname\db.propperties ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount volumes to a container on Cloud Run, but I am not sure if you need it. I guess that the properties file is read-only, so you can simply include it in your docker image.

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY target/app.jar /app/app.jar
COPY db.properties /app/db.properties
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The db.properties file will be in the applications working directory:

```java
try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream("db.properties")) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(in);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same code as you have mentioned except properties file path. properties file has userid/passwords to connect. Is it okay to include in Docker file as you have mentioned?

Comment: FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /loadvalidation
COPY ./out/artifacts/loadvalidation_jar/loadvalidation.jar /loadvalidation/loadvalidation.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/loadvalidation/loadvalidation.jar"]

Comment: Well, it depends on your workflow, it's not perfect I guess. You may consider reading properties from environment variables instead of the file. You can set them in the Cloud Run console. I don't know if you use Spring Boot, but if you were, it will automatically map environment variables to properties.

Comment: I did not use springboot. It is just a native java application.